# "some time" or "some times"

Tags: grammaticality

I've found an error identification question and its answer from a website and wonder whether this was right.

The question says:

> He has been working here for sometimes.

And the answer is:

> He has been working here for some times.

A part that contains an error is "some times".

Is it right to use *some times* instead of *some time*?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Some times can be correct but is not in this case.

I believe, in this case, since it is referring to a single block of time which he has been working, and also is past tense, you would say "some time".

If it were present tense and multiple blocks of time, you would definitely say "some times", such as:

> He works here in the summer sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

It might be technically grammatically correct, but it doesn't usually make sense.

Taken literally, "he worked here for some times" might mean that he worked here at different times. Maybe he worked here from 2000-2004, then quit and got a different job from 2004-2005, then he came back 2005-2007. I would still expect the sentence to be worded differently though.

So the answer is no, I don't think "some times" is correct in this case.